# Enabling Jetpack Slideshow plugin on a website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've been creating a separate blog page on a custom website and using the Wordpress REST API to pull the post data onto the site. I've been following this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) on how to pull the posts. My problem now is to find a way to make the Jetpack slideshow plugin working on the website.
Instead of the plugin, it displays:

> This slideshow requires JavaScript.

Nothing on the documentation mentioned on how to enable the plugin. I'm hoping you all may know a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a quick solution, I've simply copied the scripts and stylesheet that the jetpack plugins used and placed it on the external webpage.

It works but not sure if this is the best solution.